# How can I distribute mandatory settings (system and LibreOffice settings)?

Tags: configuration, libreoffice, users, settings, system

The last PCI settings:

- Users may not change their screen saver timeout, it has to be set to
  5 minutes. And locked so that no configuration can be made by the user.
- Users must always unlock their screen when the automatic
  screen saver is enabled and a keystroke or mouse movement is
  initiated by the user. This setting must be locked as well.

I also want to push default LibreOffice settings e.g. the hardware acceleration in LO is breaking the full screen presentation option in Impress. So disabling that is important.

On Ubuntu 11.04 I could do this by adding the configuration below in `/etc/gconf/gconf.xml.mandatory/`. But that doesn't work anymore for the screen saver in 12.04.

I would like to know how I can make these settings mandatory in an easy way. This must also work for new machines as well, so copying profiles is not a solution.

```
<gconf>
        <dir name="desktop">
                <dir name="gnome">
                        <dir name="session">
                                <entry name="idle_delay" mtime="1292927092" type="int" value="5"/>
                        </dir>
                </dir>
        </dir>
        <dir name="apps">
                <dir name="gnome-screensaver">
                        <entry name="idle_activation_enabled" mtime="1300290816" type="bool" value="true"/>
                        <entry name="lock_enabled" mtime="1300290814" type="bool" value="true"/>

                </dir>
        </dir>
                <dir name="gnome-power-manager">
                        <dir name="lock">
                                <entry name="use_screensaver_settings" mtime="1300291577" type="bool" value="true"/>

                        </dir>
                </dir>
</gconf>
```

---

EDIT: It didn't work.

Comment: That would work for an upgrade yes, but not for new users. And as I explained the configuration has changed, I don't know how to enforce those same settings with 12.04.

Comment: @ kamil, could you elaborate on that solution? Please note that this is not just for a transition but also for newly kickstarted Ubuntu desktops. And the settings of 11.04 don't work on 12.04 as I mentioned twice now.

Comment: Anyone? Please?

Comment: I've found a way! I'll exercise this for a bit and then I'll write some documentation for Debian. I'll post the link here when done.

Comment: Hi @user95339, did you ever write up your solution? :)

Comment: If you'd be willing to summarize the solution here *and* write Debian documentation (and link to your Debian documentation in [your self-answer here](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/)), that would probably be the best of both worlds!